How do I snap the edges of hex tiles together?
Trying to make assets for a hex-grid map-based game. How do I set Blender snapping so that the corners/edges of the hex tiles snap together? Are there any addons that make it easier?


You can use existing snapping functionality in many different ways to achieve this. One way would be to use Base Point functionality. You can press  B  while in transform operation to define base point used for snapping and snap it to something:

Note that it's affected by snapping settings, so you probably want vertex snapping enabled:


Amazing! Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for!
